# IOS: NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nstimeinterval

I am trying to create something similar to Kevin Lawler's Timeago for future dates. It seems that using dateFormatter and setting SetDoesRelativeDateFormatting:YES is the closest native api to that library or similar libraries in other languages.  Apple provides the sample code below that I have working.  However, its future capability is limited to swapping tomorrow for tomorrow's date and so I am trying to combine it with NSDateFormatter.  For some reason, however, I can't get the two to work together.

Apple reference code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle; 
dateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = YES;

NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60*60*24*3];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"dateString: %@", dateString); //logs valid output
```

If instead of using timestyle or datestyle, however, I use `setDateFormat` when I log out the result, I get nil.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz"];
dateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = YES;
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60*60*24*3];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"dateString: %@", dateString); //logs blank
```

Does `doesRelativeDateFormatting` only work with `NSDateFormatterMediumStyle` or can you combine it with setDateFormat in some way that I am not seeing?

Comment: Update your question with some example input and output that want.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code it worked for me

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
    dateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = YES;

    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60*60*24*3];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"dateString: %@", dateString); //logs valid output


    dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz"];
    dateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = NO;
    date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60*60*24*3];
    dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"dateString: %@", dateString); //logs date correctly
```